# Разархивирование файлов

Tags: android

С загрузкой я разобрался, гружу архивом, но теперь новая проблема, архив нужно распаковать, я нашел класс для распаковки архива, но при распакове, на ее время приложение виснет и даже выдает предложение о завершении, да после распаковки все нормально, но вот юзерам это не объяснить будет... Код разархиватора:

```
public class Decompress 
{ 
    private String _zipFile; 
    private String _location;

    public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) { 
        _zipFile = zipFile; 
        _location = location;

        _dirChecker(""); 
    }

    public void unzip() { 
        try { 
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
            ZipEntry ze = null; 
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
                Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

                if(ze.isDirectory()) 
                { 
                    _dirChecker(ze.getName()); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName()); 
                    for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) { 
                        fout.write(c); 
                    }

                    zin.closeEntry(); 
                    fout.close(); 
                }

            } 
            zin.close(); 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
        }

    }

    private void _dirChecker(String dir) { 
        File f = new File(_location + dir);

        if(!f.isDirectory()) { 
            f.mkdirs(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Т.е. он очень долго распаковывает файлы не отвечая на запросы?

Comment: Да

Comment: Есть два возможных варианта: распаралелить процесс, чтобы разархивирование происходило на заднем плане с возможностью отказа от него; разбить процесс разархивирования на куски.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй вариант, о котором я говорил.

```
public class Decompress 
{ 
  private String _zipFile; 
  private String _location;
  private FileInputStream fin;
  private ZipInputStream zin;
  private ZipEntry ze;
  private FileOutputStream fout

  public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) { 
    _zipFile = zipFile; 
    _location = location;

    _dirChecker(""); 
    try {
      fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
      zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
      ze = null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) { 
      Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
    }
  }

  public ~Decompress() {
    Close();
  }

  public void Close() {
    zin.close();
  }

  public int unzip(int count) { 
    try {
      int read = 0;
      if (ze == null) {
        ze = zin.getNextEntry();
        if (ze == null)          
          return -1;
        else {
          Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());          
          if (!ze.isDirectory()) {
            fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName());
          }
      }
      if(ze.isDirectory()) 
      { 
        _dirChecker(ze.getName());
        ze = null;
      } 
      else 
      {
        for (int c = zin.read(); (c != -1)&&(read < count); c = zin.read()) { 
          fout.write(c); 
        }
        if (c == -1) {
          zin.closeEntry();
          fout.close();
          ze = null;
        }
      }
      return read;      
    }
  } catch(Exception e) { 
    Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
  }  
}

private void _dirChecker(String dir) { 
  File f = new File(_location + dir);

  if(!f.isDirectory()) { 
    f.mkdirs(); 
  } 
}

}
```

И пример использования.

```
int res = 0;
int progress = 0;
Decompress dec = new Decompress("lala.zip", ".");
while(res != -1) {
  res = dec.unzip(256);
  progress++;
  //Обработка сообщений
  if(terminated) break;
}
```